# Find text bounded by '&' symbol

Tags: python, regex

Example

```
x='RTRV:&PM_DICT[&PM_LIST&:&PM_LIST&]&'
```

What is the regular expression which will generate data like below?

```
PM_DICT[
PM_LIST
PM_LIST
]
```

All texts within the "&" symbols.

Comment: Why `:` is excluded?

Comment: What did you try already? Why isn't it working?

Comment: Why did you revert @falsetru's edit? It was cleaner. I restored it.

Answer (score 2):

```
x='RTRV:&PM_DICT[&PM_LIST&:&PM_LIST&]&'
>>> x.split("&")[1:]
['PM_DICT[', 'PM_LIST', ':', 'PM_LIST', ']', '']
```

Or remove empty items

```
>>> filter(lambda i: len(i) > 0, x.split("&")[1:])
['PM_DICT[', 'PM_LIST', ':', 'PM_LIST', ']']
```

The `:` is mysteriously missing in your question. Where did it go? Into a `filter` perhaps?

```
>>> forbidden_items = set(["", ":", "RTRV:"])
>>> filter(lambda i: i not in forbidden_items, x.split("&"))
['PM_DICT[', 'PM_LIST', 'PM_LIST', ']']
```

Comment: It should be `[1:-1]`. Otherwise parts after the `&` is included.

Comment: More questions than answers. As you said, what about ":"?

Comment: Filtering empty strings are not enough. Think about `x = 'RTRV:&PM_DICT[&PM_LIST&:&PM_LIST&]&THIS_SHOULD_BE_EXLUDED'`

Comment: I added a filter. This is far too much effort for a question with so little effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x
'RTRV:&PM_DICT[&PM_LIST&:&PM_LIST&]&'
>>> re.split('&',x)[1:]
['PM_DICT[', 'PM_LIST', ':', 'PM_LIST', ']', '']
>>> x.split('&')[1:]
['PM_DICT[', 'PM_LIST', ':', 'PM_LIST', ']', '']
```

Comment: That's basically a duplicate of as my answer.

Comment: you can downvote if you feel its copied. Also there is a regex spilt in there.

Comment: I don't think you copy-pasted it (I edited that to 'duplicate'). Just that there's no good reason to use the `re` library.